# Replace and add data in pandas automatically （with some filter）

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, replace

I'm learning pandas now, I meet a problem when I want to add something automatically into dataframe in pandas.
Here is my data

```
import pandas 
Data=pandas.read_excel(r'D:\pandas.test.xlsx',sheetname='Sheet1')
print Data

Name    N          P

cd05233-SDR_c   237   41.872792
smart00895-FCD   215   37.985866
pfam00126-HTH_1   206   36.395760
pfam07729-FCD   202   35.689046
pfam00165-HTH_AraC   197   34.805654
```

I want to add a new column'Classification'
when the item in Name contains 'cd' ,the 'Classification' changes to 'cd',

I write commands like this:

```
Data[''Classification'']='N'
Data[Data.Name.str.contains('cd')].iat[0,3]='cd'
print Data
```

Data is:

```
Name    N          P           classification

cd05233-SDR_c   237   41.872792               N
smart00895-FCD   215   37.985866               N
pfam00126-HTH_1   206   36.395760               N
pfam07729-FCD   202   35.689046               N
pfam00165-HTH_AraC   197   34.805654               N
```

Nothing happens after the program, could anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
Data.loc[Data.Name.str.contains('cd'), 'Classification'] = 'cd'
```

If need `cd` and `n`:

```
Data['Classification'] = np.where(Data.Name.str.contains('cd'), 'cd', 'n')
```

Comment: @cc1000ml Accept the answer if your problem is solved :)

Comment: Do you have some problem?